# Query Collection using Where with a less than or greater than statement in it?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

Does backbone collections using `.where()` or like function accept some form of less/greater-than statements such as `<=`, `>=`, `<`, `>`

I cant find anything in the documentation that says anything either way

Answer (score 2):

No, `where` doesn't support that. From the [fine manual](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-where):

> **where** `collection.where(attributes)`
>
> Return an array of all the models in a collection that match the passed **attributes**. Useful for simple cases of `filter`.

`where` is just a `filter` call in disguise so you can use [`filter`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) (which is [mixed into Backbone collections](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods)) directly for more complicated things:

```
var matches = collection.filter(function(m) {
    /* check model `m` here */
});
```

Comment: This is what Im finding looking at underscores docs. Now Im just trying to figure out how to do multiple parameters at once. Since the filters I am trying to create have a requirement to support multiple values to search against example: Status = Error, TimeStamp <= xxx, Location = yyy (multiple values at once, that may not always exist in the condition)

Comment: @chris use `if`, `||`, `&&` etc you define your conditions... `if(Status == 'Error' || (TimeStamp <= xxx && Location == yyy)) return true; else if(){}` and so on.